# -bash: cd: Downloads: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, directory, cd

Why does `cd Downloads` fail with "No such file or directory"? Even tho I know that it is case-sensitive What procedure is missing during installation or to run Ubuntu on Windows 10?

Comment: `cd ~/Downloads`

Comment: still the problem is not fixed.

Comment: Please add output of `ls ~` to your question.

Comment: If any doubt, please run the `pwd` command to show your current location. If you are in e.g. `~/Documents` the "cd" command is `cd ../Downloads/`

Comment: If by *"Ubuntu on Windows 10"* you mean **Windows Subsystem for Linux**, then it's a CLI-only version of Ubuntu and doesn't have the XDG ~/Desktop, ~/Documents etc. folders by default. You can of course create them if you want.

Answer (score 1):

`cd Downloads` will fail with "No such file or directory", because no file or directory with the name `Downloads` is found in the current directory.

When you are in the terminal, a directory is your current default working directory. That is where the system will find and save files, or create folders, if you do not explicitly say yourself where to do that.

At first, that directory is your home directory, `/home/<yourlogin>/`, shortcut notation: `~`. With the `cd Downloads` command, the system will look for a 'Downloads' directory in your current directory. If it is there, `Downloads` will be your new current directory. If it is not there, the system tells you.

Instead of just the name, you can also specify a full pathname, e.g. `~/Downloads`, shortcut for `/home/<yourlogin>/Downloads`. Then, it does not matter what your current directory is: the command will work, provided the directory actually does exist in the location you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If your system interface is using some non-English language, the `Downloads` directory may be called in some other language.

You can check it by running `ls ~`.