# Installing Proton Bridge pubkey issue

Tags: thunderbird

To start off I am a very green linux user. So if I'm asking something that's 'common sense' then there it is.

I'm trying to setup Protonmail on Unbuntu with Thunderbird. Part of the process I need to import the pubkey. I'm following these instructions on the Protonmail webpage [here](https://proton.me/support/installing-bridge-linux-deb-file).

I saved the pub_key.gpg to the download folders (as instructed save link as). Though it didn't say where to save. I then use the following code:

```
gpg --dearmor --output debsig.gpg bridge_pubkey.gpg
```

And got this error:

```
gpg: can't open 'bridge_pubkey.gpg': No such file or directory
gpg: dearmoring failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: where are you running that line? in the downloads folder? If not, ether `cd` to the downloads folder to run that line, or move the key file to the folder you're working in in the shell.

Comment: Thank you - that seemed to work (for this step).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [-bash: cd: Downloads: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392483/bash-cd-downloads-no-such-file-or-directory)