# Remove file not working

Tags: command-line, system

I have just installed a php file for testing.

The command:

```
sudo rm info.php
```

Also, checking other posts here, and calling rm help, I tryed:

```
rm -r info.php
```

Outputs:
rm: cannot remove 'info.php': No such file or directory

The file can be seen on browser.

Any other suggestion please?

Comment: what are you trying to do? `rm` *removes* a file, after running `sudo rm info.php` you *deleted* the file, so of course it doesn't exist anymore

Comment: It is still showing on my browser. I am on incognito, refreshed cookies...

Comment: how are you opening it in your browser? did you do the `rm` command *in the folder where the file is*? can you open up the GUI file manager and find the file?

Comment: https://ip:info.php

Comment: if it's not a site on the internet, then I won't be able to see it, and also it won't matter if you refresh cookies/go in incognito mode

Comment: thanks Esther, I will download the GUI later and see it. Ur right...

Comment: you don't need to download any GUI, it comes with Ubuntu Desktop. Unless you're running the server version?

Comment: yes, on a remote instance

Comment: clearly the file isn't where you think it is (or you're running the `rm` command in the wrong place). Find where the file is, and *in that folder* run `rm info.php`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [-bash: cd: Downloads: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392483/bash-cd-downloads-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: thanks @karel that one is sorted out, I'm now struggling with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on my domain...

Comment: That would be a matter for a separate question IINM.